# matplotlib - How to plot a random-oriented rectangle (or any shape)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to draw a line whose width is specified in the data unit. In this case, simply doing

```
plot(x, y, linewidth=1)
```

would fail, as the `linewidth` there is NOT specified in data unit.

To do this, I find [`fill_between()`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html), but I find all the examples given here are of the format

```
fill_between(x, y1, y2)
```

which means, the `x` is always shared by `y1` and `y2`.

So **what if `y1` and `y2` don't share the same `x`?**

e.g. I wish to fill between `line1=[(0, 0), (2, 2)]` and `line2=[(-1, 1), (1, 3)]` (essentially, they form a rectangle). In this case, I want something like

```
fill_between(x1, x2, y1, y2)
```

Apparently, it is not working as desired:

```
In [132]: x1 = [0,2]
   .....: x2 = [-1, 1]
   .....: y1 = [0,2]
   .....: y2 = [1,3]
   .....: fill_between(x1, x2, y1, y2)
   .....: 
Out[132]: <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection at 0x3e5b230>
```

[image]

How should I plot in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! I would suggest you that do not limit yourself in the `fill_between` function. I always regard it as beneficial to *look deep inside* the things. Let's dive into the essence of the Python drawing.

[The object underlying all of the `matplotlib.patch` objects is the `Path`.](http://matplotlib.org/users/path_tutorial.html)

Therefore, if you master the `Path`, you basically can draw whatever you like in whatever manner. Let's now see how do we achieve your goal with the magical `Path`.

To get the rectangle you mentioned in the question, only a bit of adaption on the example is needed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches

verts = [(0., 0.), # left, bottom
         (-1., 1.), # left, top
         (1., 3.), # right, top
         (2., 2.), # right, bottom
         (0., 0.),] # ignored

codes = [Path.MOVETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.CLOSEPOLY,]

path = Path(verts, codes)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='orange', lw=2)
ax.add_patch(patch) 
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

I think the code is so straightforward and self-explanatory that I do not need to waste my words on it. Just copy and paste and run it, you will get this, exactly what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think this is a more general solution.

Answer (score 7):

Even simpler, [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle)

```
rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((.25, .25), .25, .5, angle=45)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect)
plt.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this requires me to calculate the angle for not-so-nicely-oriented rectangles, right?

Comment: you know where the corners are, getting the angle is just a matter of `np.atan2`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of plotting the lines, you can draw the filled area as a [polygon](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon). To do this, you need to concatenate `x1` with the reverse of `x2` and do the same for `y1` and `y2`. Something like this:

```
In [1]: from pylab import *
In [2]: x1 = arange(0,11,2)
In [3]: x2 = arange(0,11)
In [4]: y1 = x1**2+1
In [5]: y2 = x2**2-1
In [6]: xy = c_[r_[x1,x2[::-1]], r_[y1,y2[::-1]]]
In [7]: ax = subplot(111) # we need an axis first
In [8]: ax.add_patch(Polygon(xy))
Out[8]: <matplotlib.patches.Polygon at 0x3bff990>
In [9]: axis([0,10,-10,110]) # axis does not automatically zoom to a patch
Out[9]: [0, 10, -10, 110]
In [10]: show()
```